# stretch background image inside a button to fill button

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a button width a large image as the background.  The image fits so that it takes up all vertical space of the button, but the image will be repeated horizontally unless I use no-repeat, in which case it is just left as empty space (still not filling horizontally).

```
<button class="tiles" style="padding: 0px; background: url(../static/bilder/tür.jpg); background-size: contain; background-repeat: no-repeat" v-if="selectedCategory==''" >
```

How can I style this to make it stretch the whole width of the button?  It's okay if the proportions are messed up.

Comment: Change: background-size: cover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `background-size: 100% 100%;` which will stretch image and mess up proportions or `background-size: cover;` which will scale image, preserve proportions and crop the image

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Answer (score 1):

First remove `background-size: contain;` of inline style, after it use :

```
button {
   background-size: cover;
}
```

```css
button {
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<button class="tiles" style="padding: 0px; background: url(http://www.incendia.net/hexquilts/image112.png);  background-repeat: no-repeat; color: #FFF" v-if="selectedCategory==''">This is test</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
background-size: cover;
background-position: center center;
```

or try adding an explicit size of the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can get like this,

if you give height and width or by giving background-size properties as per the parent div then the image looks squashed.

You should get a bigger image and can position it as per your requirement.

I recommend use a image tag and use image responsive class so that it works for all resolutions.